# When uboxing truffle react, there is no package.json file. As a result, I cannot start the program

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, ethereum, truffle

I followed the instruction from truffle's site to unbox reacthttps://github.com/truffle-box/react-box

However, when I type in 'npm run start', I get the error

```
npm ERR! path D:\COMP495\testReact\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\COMP495\testReact\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\l_zha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-21T12_45_14_733Z-debug.log
```

I may note, there is no 'package.json' file in my root directory for whatever reason. There is a 'package.json' file in my client folder, so I can run React, though unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to run it from the Client directory. From there, in /Client/src/ I need to add the contracts folder from /build/contracts/, NOT /contracts/ from the root directory as there is no json file there.